# Visualforce.remoting.manager.invokeAction Clarification

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I am revisiting old code from an old developer and I am having trouble reading a line they wrote:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(fetchAttachmentAndNote, parentId, function(result, event) {..}
```

I have been digging around about javascript remoting and haven't found anything too detailed other then [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm). Which doesn't explain if there is a minimum requirement for what needs to be included, or what the functionality of `function(result, event)` is.

According the the documentation there should be:

```
{!@RemoteAction.Classname.MethodName}, 
parameters, 
call back function, 
configuration details
```

If `fetchAttachmentAndNote` is a function that returns a list of attachments, what does that make `parentId`? Is `parentId` the parameter? Which function does the parameter belong to? And what is being passed into `result`? Could anyone break down the `function(result, event)` a little more for me?

I know that you would need to see the rest of the code to fully know what is going on here but any breakdown of this line on Remoting would be helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you included:

- `fetchAttachmentAndNote` is your action
- `parentId` is the only parameter
- `function(result, event)` is your callback
- you have not specified any configuration details

If you wrote a `@RemoteAction` that accepts more parameters, they would follow parentId. If you want to specify configuration details, add an object at the end. For example:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '<action>', param1, param2, param3
    function (result, event) {
        // callback logic
    },
    {
        // configuration
    }
);
```

You can see more examples of [Configuring a JavaScript Remoting Request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm?search_text=remoteaction) in the `Visualforce Developer Guide`. Also useful is [Namespaces and JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_namespaces.htm?search_text=remoteaction)
:

> You can use the $RemoteAction global to automatically resolve the correct namespace, if any, for your remote action. This makes it easier to work with namespaces, especially for pages that make remoting calls to methods provided in packages.
>
> To use this facility, you must explicitly invoke JavaScript remoting. The pattern for doing this is:
>
> ```
> Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
>    'fully_qualified_remote_action', 
>     invocation_parameters
> );
> ```
>
> The fully qualified remote action is a string that represents the complete path to the remote action method, including namespace, base class, and so on: `namespace[.BaseClass][.ContainingClass].ConcreteClass.Method`. Use `$RemoteAction` in an expression to automatically resolve the namespace, for example `{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccount}`.
>
> Invocation parameters are the arguments used to perform the remote method invocation, and are the same arguments used to make a standard remoting call:
>
> - The parameters to send to the @RemoteAction method, if any.
> - The callback function, which handles the returned result.
> - Configuration details for the invocation, if any.
>
> For example, you might define a remote invocation to retrieve an account like this:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function getRemoteAccount() {
>     var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;
>
>     Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
>         '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccount}', 
>         accountName, 
>         function(result, event){
>             if (event.status) {
>                 document.getElementById('acctId').innerHTML = result.Id
>                 document.getElementById('acctName').innerHTML = result.Name;
>             } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
>                 document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
>             } else {
>                 document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
>             }
>         }, 
>         {escape: true}
>     );
> }
> </script>
> ```
>
> This JavaScript remoting call doesn’t need to know the details of the namespace in which the controller is defined, whether it’s in your own namespace or something provided by an installed package. It also handles the situation where your organization doesn’t have a namespace defined.

Comment: So `function (result, event)` handles the returned result of `fetchAttachmentAndNote` ? and `parentId` is the param for:  `List<NotesAttachmentModel> fetchAttachmentAndNote (string review_id)`?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Is it possible to have more than 1 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction in a VF page?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is yes, but also unsure why anyone would still be using Visualforce.